# Where to find Azure Hybrid Connection Logs

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections

Is there a way to enable Logs related to azure Hybrid Connection. My ChatBot sends requests to an on-premise API through Azure Hybrid Connection. Sometimes we are getting intermittent connectivity issues. For example 1 out of 10 connection fails. But still, it's not happening on a regular basis

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Azure Hybrid Connection Manager which lives in your on-premise machine will create event logs. You'll find them under Application and Service Logs/Microsoft/ServiceBus/Client.

You can learn more here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/troubleshooting-hybrid-connections-with-logging/ba-p/392384